# IZUG846W: An HTTP request for a z/OSMF REST service was received from a remote site

Tags: mainframe, zos, zosmf

I setup z/OSMF and I am receiving this error when attempting to access the url `https://my.zos.com/zosmf/restjobs/jobs`.

> { “errorID”:“IZUG846W”,“errorMsg”:“IZUG846W: An HTTP request for a
>   z/OSMF REST service was received from a remote site. The request was
>   rejected, however, because the remote site \“\” is not permitted to
>   z/OSMF server \“IZUSVR\” on target system \“my.zos.com\” .“}

The error message is does not provide sufficient information to identify the root cause.  Has someone else hit this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is preferable, and I believe it is the default, to keep CSRF_SWITCH(ON), which requires a whitelist to be setup so that only hosts in the whitelist can originate requests.

The whitelist is a RACF `ZMFAPLA` resource class profile of the form `IZUDFLT.ZOSMF.REST.<zosmf-service>.<reversed-host-name>`.  All such profiles must be defined with UACC(NONE) and permit READ access to the server's ID (default is IZUSVR).

An example profile `IZUDFLT.ZOSMF.REST.*.com.whoa.test.myserver`, will allow inbound cross-origin requests from the host name myserver.test.whoa.com.  Same origin requests such as those from a web browser that is accessing the z/OSMF host directly are not subject to CSRF protection.

Comment: Thanks John.  That is why I called out that z/OSMF is setup in a secure mode and provided references to other materials for consideration.

Answer (score 2):

If you are generating the REST request yourself you can add the header X-CSRF-ZOSMF-HEADER with any value to get around this.  Firefox postman for example lets you add the header [I've got a picture of before and after in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jmf0.png)

Another good way to deal with a fussy z/OSMF server is to drive the API through CURL

curl -k -H "X-CSRF-ZOSMF-HEADER: dummy" -u : https://:/zosmf/restfiles/ds?dslevel=T*

In zowe.org we provide a set of REST APIs that don't insist on the header and abstract some of the nuances of z/OSMF, as well as a command line interface and a nifty looking JES explorer as well as couple of file explorers for data sets and USS files that run in a browser, so if you've got a moment swing by zowe.org and let us know if it helps at all.

Cheers,

Joe

Answer (score 1):

By default z/OSMF is configured in a secure mode so as not to open up an accidental security hole.  The message provided indicates that the remote system (source of the REST call) may potentially be unsecure.  This means that the request is denied.

One way of avoiding this issue is to modify the `IZUPRMnn` member that initializes z/OSMF.  The parameter:

`CSRF_SWITCH(ON)` which is the default can be changed to 
`CSRF_SWITCH(OFF)` this disables the cross site scripting safety mechanism.

The parameters for z/OSMF can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.izua300/izuconfig_IZUPRMxx.htm).

The specific entry for `CSRF_SWITCH` is included for reference below and is based on z/OS 2.3.

> **CSRF_SWITCH(ON|OFF)**
>
> Indicates whether Cross Site Request Forgery
>   (CSRF) custom header checking is enabled for REST API requests. By
>   default, CSRF_SWITCH is set to ON to ensure that your installation is
>   protected against CSRF attacks. However, in some limited cases, such
>   as for testing, you might choose to temporarily disable CSRF checking
>   by setting CSRF_SWITCH=OFF. However, it is recommended that you leave
>   this setting enabled to prevent CSRF attacks. For more information,
>   see IBM z/OS Management Facility Programming Guide. Default: ON

More information on z/OSMF Configuration can be be found [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R3sc278420/$file/izua700_v2r3.pdf)